# sshpass through regular ssh client

Tags: ssh, sshpass

I am using an application that uses `/usr/bin/ssh` and requires passwordless authentication. Meanwhile I want to use this with a server that requires *both* publickey and password authentication at the same time. Just using `sshpass` is a good solution in most circumstances (given that my secret password is safe and that I am also using safe public key authentication at the same time), but `sshpass` wraps around `ssh` and not the other way around.

How can I use `sshpass` when `/usr/bin/ssh x` is called? My current workaround is the config below. It works, but it hops from the target server to itself. I would rather not have this overhead.

```
Host x
    HostName xxx.xxx.xx
    ProxyCommand sshpass -f passwordfile ssh -W %h:%p xxx.xxx.xx
```

Is there a way to get the same result without hopping to the server itself?

(Otherwise - for future people with the same problem - the above config is a workable solution.)

Comment: what sort of application? GUI or CLI? other than running SSH, what else does it do? If it just runs SSH, there may be a chance to wrap the whole application inside sshpass, i.e. `sshpass theapplication ...` instead of `sshpass ssh ...`

Comment: @ilkkachu The application does more than just running ssh commands and wrapping it with sshpass does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the application that I'm using is a CLI program that searches for `ssh` in `$PATH`, it is possible to modify PATH to include a special `ssh` command that is actually a `sshpass` wrapper.

Wrap `sshpass` into a executable called `ssh`:

`/path/to/bin/ssh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sshpass -f /path/to/passwordfile ssh "$@"
```

Then prepend the parent dir of the custom `ssh` to PATH when running `myapp` by adding the following alias in `.zshrc` or `.bashrc`:

```
alias myapp="PATH=/path/to/bin:$PATH myapp"
```